# Issue while running war on wildfly jboss

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to run my war file on wildfly jboss(8.1) and getting below error on hitting url while same war is working fine on jboss 7.1. Kindly help me on it if anyone have idea when this error comes.

```
15:16:11,331 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default I/O-2) Blocking request failed HttpServerExchange{ GET /smareporting/pirpt}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1871) [rt.jar:1.7.0_65]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.setupServletChains(ServletPathMatches.java:311)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getData(ServletPathMatches.java:124)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletPathMatches.getServletHandlerByPath(ServletPathMatches.java:75)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:108)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PathHandler.handleRequest(PathHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.HttpContinueReadHandler.handleRequest(HttpContinueReadHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:49)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.SetHeaderHandler.handleRequest(SetHeaderHandler.java:49)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.NameVirtualHostHandler.handleRequest(NameVirtualHostHandler.java:53)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.error.SimpleErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SimpleErrorPageHandler.java:76)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.CanonicalPathHandler.handleRequest(CanonicalPathHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.ChannelUpgradeHandler.handleRequest(ChannelUpgradeHandler.java:158)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEventWithNoRunningRequest(HttpReadListener.java:156)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:91)
at io.undertow.server.protocol.http.HttpReadListener.handleEvent(HttpReadListener.java:45)
at org.xnio.ChannelListeners.invokeChannelListener(ChannelListeners.java:92) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at org.xnio.conduits.ReadReadyHandler$ChannelListenerHandler.readReady(ReadReadyHandler.java:66) [xnio-api-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at org.xnio.nio.NioSocketConduit.handleReady(NioSocketConduit.java:87) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
at org.xnio.nio.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:539) [xnio-nio-3.2.2.Final.jar:3.2.2.Final]
```

Comment: If possible, you might try to use Wildfly 8.2 or 9. Even if you can't use them, if the error does not occur on these version, you know that it is probably not an application error

Comment: Thanks. You are right, Application is working perfect on 8.2 and 8.2.1. looks like some issue with jboss 8.1